# How do I block a Google AdSense advertiser's ads from appearing on my site?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I'm trying to block particular ads in Google Adsense that don't fit my site.

There are some really annoying ads from www.plus500.com but I can't seem to get rid of all ads from them. How can I find out what the exact url of the ad is so that I can block it?

I installed firebug but am unable to easily find urls with it.

Answer (score 2):

> To allow or block all ads for a
>   particular advertiser, locate an ad
>   group related to that advertiser in
>   the Ad Review Center. In the Review
>   settings drop-down, choose either
>   'Allow all ads from this advertiser'
>   or 'Block all ads from this
>   advertiser', depending on your
>   preference.

[How do I allow or block all ads for selected advertisers?](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44116) topic at Google AdSense documentation

AdSense's [Filtering and Blocking Ads](http://www.google.com/support/adsense/bin/topic.py?topic=154) documentation provides further instructions for identifying and blocking advertisers.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the Competitive Ad Filter in your Google AdSense manager. (https://www.google.com/adsense/filter-online -- you'll have to be logged in to get there)

Add plus500.com to the list of blocked domains. It doesn't really have to be a competitor. I have a huge list, from annoying to non-matching, to [block low paying ads](http://www.makemoneywritingonline.com/earn-money-online/google-analytics-to-protect-adsense-earnings/).

Note that this won't work if those ads are being served through another party like an ad network. In that case, you would have to block the ad network too.

Right click on the ad (don't click on it for real) and choose Copy URL. Then go paste that URL in a text editor. Somewhere in the middle you will find a domain name. Block that domain name. With Firebug, put your mouse over the ad and right click to choose Inspect Element and then do the same as above.

You can't block Flash ads this way since the source URL is not where the ad actually comes from. For that you'll have to peek into the Flash code. Here is a tip on finding out [where flash AdSense ads come from](http://www.makemoneywritingonline.com/site-news/adsense-competitive-filter-not-working-filtering-atdmt-google/).